# How to access to value from multiple keys for a dictionary in python3?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, multidimensional-array

Have a multidimensional dictionary, by example:

```py
a = {
    'b': {
        'c': {
            'd': 1
        }
    }
}
```

How to access to value dynamically from a specific path on function?, by example:

```py
def get_value(path):
   ???
```

How to send the keys and specific dimension?, by example, using `'b.c.d'` or `['b','c','d']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursion:

```py
def get_value(dct, path):
    if len(path) == 1:
        return dct[path[0]]
    return get_value(dct[path[0]], path[1:])


a = {"b": {"c": {"d": 1}}}
print(get_value(a, ["b", "c", "d"]))
```

Prints:

```
1
```